# Google: reverse search image by date?

Tags: images, search, date, search-engines

Each time I try to combine the two I fail, yet this would be great to find the original version of an image.

For time range:
http://google.com/#q=search+string&tbm=isch&tbs=cdr%3A1%2Ccd_min%3A2000%2Ccd_max%3A2010
where:
&tbm = image search
&tbs = time range

For reverse image search:
http://google.com/#q=search+string&tbm=isch&tbs=TYPE:DATA
where:
&tbs = reverse image search
TYPE = simg for JP?G; and sbi for png and gif,
DATA = image data that came from, for example:
http://google.com/searchbyimage?image_url=https://cdn.sstatic.net/stackoverflow/img/apple-touch-icon.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google added the feature I wished they had around one week ago. Search:
http://www.google.com/searchbyimage?image_url=https://....[jp?g,png,gif] then click: → Search tools → Time → Custom range...

I wish I remember what image I was looking for.

Comment: There's no custom range for images any more. They've removed it.